# Norm of linear functional in $W^{1,2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to find the norm of the following linear functional:

$\phi:W^{1,2}_{[0,1]} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$\phi(f)=\int^1_0t\cdot f(t)+ f^{'}(t) dt $

The norm is: $||f||_{W^{1,2}}=||f||_2+||f^{'}||_2$

I didn't get too far:

$|\phi|=|\int^1_0t\cdot f(t)+ f^{'}(t) dt|\leq\int^1_0 |tf| +\int^1_0 |f^{'}|$

And I should get something like this:

$||\phi||\leq L(||f||_2+||f^{'}||_2 )$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the norm in $W^{1,2}$. Where does the $f$ in your estimate has gone?

Comment: @gerw Thanks, I edited the post, and ||f||_{W^{1,2}}=||f||_2+||f^{'}||_2 is the norm.

Comment: Try Cauchy-Schwarz: $ \int^1_0 |tf| \le \|t\|_2 \|f\|_2 $ and so on. Also, do you really want to find the precise norm, or just have an inequality like $||\phi||\leq L(||f||_2+||f'||_2 )$?

Comment: @Behaviour Yes, I want to find the precise norm.